# R data.table warnings about columns not being removed, only in RStudio?

Tags: r, data.table, rstudio-server

Consider the below example code, which is based on an actual problem I am encountering. Everything below will run without any problems.

```
library(data.table)

pers_ids <- expand.grid(LETTERS,LETTERS,1:26,LETTERS,LETTERS)
pers_ids <- paste(pers_ids$Var1,
                  pers_ids$Var2,
                  pers_ids$Var3,
                  pers_ids$Var4,
                  pers_ids$Var5,
                  sep = "")

dt_pers_scores <- data.table(pers_id = pers_ids,
                             score1 = sample(x = 0:1,size = length(pers_ids),replace = TRUE,prob = c(0.4,0.6)),
                             score2 = sample(x = 0:1,size = length(pers_ids),replace = TRUE,prob = c(0.1,0.9)),
                             score3 = sample(x = 0:1,size = length(pers_ids),replace = TRUE,prob = c(0.2,0.8)),
                             score4 = sample(x = 0:1,size = length(pers_ids),replace = TRUE,prob = c(0.7,0.3)),
                             score5 = sample(x = 0:1,size = length(pers_ids),replace = TRUE,prob = c(0.6,0.4)))

dt_pers_group_mapping <- data.table(pers_id = pers_ids,
                                    group_id = sample(x = sample(x = LETTERS,size = 10,replace = FALSE),
                                                      size = length(pers_ids),
                                                      replace = TRUE))

# Set keys
setkey(dt_pers_scores,
       pers_id)
setkey(dt_pers_group_mapping,
       pers_id)

# Join tables and summarize
dt_group_scores <- dt_pers_group_mapping[dt_pers_scores[,list(pers_id,score1,score2,score4)]]
dt_group_scores <- dt_group_scores[,!"pers_id",with = FALSE][,as.list(ifelse(test = colSums(.SD) > 0,yes = 1,no = 0)),by = group_id]
```

However, once this has run, from time to time my R session will now announce a warning, seemingly at random. I have not been able to get this to happen in the console version of R, only in RStudio Server. I've struggled to consistently get this to happen - it seems to almost occur randomly.

When it does occur, the following is the warning:

```
Warning messages:
1: In `[.data.table`(dt_group_scores, , !"pers_id", with = FALSE) :
  column(s) not removed because not found: pers_id
2: In `[.data.table`(dt_group_scores, , !"pers_id", with = FALSE) :
  column(s) not removed because not found: pers_id
3: In `[.data.table`(dt_group_scores, , !"pers_id", with = FALSE) :
  column(s) not removed because not found: pers_id
4: In `[.data.table`(dt_group_scores, , !"pers_id", with = FALSE) :
  column(s) not removed because not found: pers_id
5: In `[.data.table`(dt_group_scores, , !"pers_id", with = FALSE) :
  column(s) not removed because not found: pers_id
6: In `[.data.table`(dt_group_scores, , !"pers_id", with = FALSE) :
  column(s) not removed because not found: pers_id
```

My instinct here is that I'm doing something wrong by the way I am creating the summary table - some way in which I'm messing up by not understanding pass-by-reference, or something along those lines. But I am not sure, especially since the problem seems to be limited to RStudio Server (I haven't tried in the Desktop RStudio). What could be causing these warning messages?

EDITED TO ADD: Per comment, I have run `sessionInfo()` before executing the code, but after loading `data.table`.

```
R version 3.3.0 (2016-05-03)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: Ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C               LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8        LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8     LC_MONETARY=en_US.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8    LC_PAPER=en_US.UTF-8      
 [8] LC_NAME=C                  LC_ADDRESS=C               LC_TELEPHONE=C             LC_MEASUREMENT=en_US.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C       

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] data.table_1.9.6

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] tools_3.3.0  chron_2.3-47
```

Comment: add `sessionInfo()`, I get no warning. Maybe you run last line twice and so you override variable name in your environment and removed that column it?

Comment: @jangorecki I added it and got the same issues this AM.

Comment: You are not using any *by reference* operators so it isn't an issue here. Warning point the exact expression that raised it. I don't have ability to try RStudio Server and I cannot reproduce it on RStudio Desktop. If putting last two lines into single one will solve the problem, it means that the last line was evaluated twice somewhere along the way. `dt_group_scores <- dt_pers_group_mapping[dt_pers_scores[,list(pers_id,score1,score2,score4)]][,!"pers_id",with = FALSE][,as.list(ifelse(test = colSums(.SD) > 0,yes = 1,no = 0)),by = group_id]`

Comment: @jangorecki I have yet to identify a single consistent line that triggers the warning, which is one of the baffling things.